# react wildcard in using setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have

```
this.state = {
   modal_1: true,
   modal_abc: true,
   modal_special: true
}
```

how can I change everything that start with modal to false? is it possible with

```
this.setState({
    `modal_*`: false
})
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as wildcards in React's `setState` method or javascript's object literal. You can manualy iterate over object keys and reduce it, e.g.:

```
const newState = Object.keys(this.state).reduce((result, key) => {
  // conditionally set value of result
  result[key] = key.startsWith('modal_') ? false : this.state[key];
  return result;
}, {});
// and set new state
this.setState(newState);
```